# failed to load resource (traceur) Angular

Tags: angular

I have an error in my project. When I load my project, it doesn't show my template and gives an error.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue , did you solved this?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022526/angular-2-404-traceur-not-found