# Angular2: error at startup of the app "http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: angular

I have a brand new installation of Angular (rc1).
I think I have just created the usual 'Hello something' app but, when I launch the app from browser, I get the following error on the browser console

[image: Console log]

Can anybody explain me what I have done wrong? I must have something wrong since other much more complex things work perfectly with rc1 on my machine.

Thanks in advance

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'm2t-app',
      template: `
            Hello something
            `,
      directives: []
    })
    export class AppComponent { 
    }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MEAN2 Training Class</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <m2t-app>Loading...</m2t-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**systemjs.confing.js**

```
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: Without code, this is nearly impossible

Comment: I have added app.component.ts, main.ts and index.html in my question. systemjs.config.js is exactly the same as in the Quick startup page. Thx

Comment: make a complete demo in `http://plnkr.co` for others to check all things please.

Comment: What is the content of your `systemjs.config.js` file? Thanks!

Comment: systemjs.config.js added  Thx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the reason. At the beginning of app.component.ts I had commented an earlier version of the silly AppComponent, something like

```
/*

import { AnotherComponent } from './anotherComponent.component'
// some other code

}*/
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'm2t-app',
  template: `
        Hello something
        `,
  directives: []
})
export class AppComponent { 
}
```

Removing the comment at the beginning of the file has solved the problem.

Comment: I too got rid of traceur errors by removing a comment block. What I don't understand is how can a commented block cause errors? It seems that     `/**  */` this is the syntax for block comments for TS (in VS Code) and not     `/*  */`. However my errors persisted upon using either of the above.

Comment: The _magic_ comes courtesy of a somehow [faulty regexp in SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1408)

Comment: I am getting this error in the browser : 
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:8080/LKMonitoring/node_modules/@angular/http/index.js

But I don't see any block comments or import statements in this file!
Above all this is not even my code but core angular 2 library code.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This was actually a multi line comment in a Pipes file for me. Removed the comment and *poof*, traceur error gone. Weird.

Comment: This saved me so much time. The second time, tbh. I forgot that I had that issue a few months ago.. That's acutally so hard to notice, definitely needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 16):

I found that this error appears in multiline comments with import/export statements. We'll fix the error if we transform the statement to some incorrect form or put the statement in a singleline comment.

Example:

```
/**
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; // generate error
export class TestClass { }; // generate error

// import { Component } from '@angular/core'; // correct
// export class TestClass { }; // correct

impot { Component } from '@angular/core'; // correct
export clas TestClass { }; // correct
*/
```

Comment: Strange but somehow this was the reason in my case. Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For other people who get this error and dont have comments in their code. I encountered this error and solved this by double checking my systemjs.config.js file.

While you may not have this exact problem in your systemjs.config.js file, it does demonstrate that the /traceur 404(Not Found) error may be coming from your systemjs.config.js file.

I had

```
  var packages = {
'app_spa': { main: 'app.component.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' },
```

and I changed it to

```
  var packages = {
'app_spa': { main: 'app.component.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

and the error went away.

Answer (score 5):

you dont need to define angular-in-memory-web-api in packages section.
remove  that defination in packages;

```
'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

instead of define   `'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'` at map section. it works fine.

[check this out](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1408)

Comment: This worked for me! Could you explain what this change effects?

Comment: check the file node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js

Comment: the problem is occured after angular 2.1.0 RC. that export statement in the file, so it still needs to be transpiled. You probably need to use angular bundle for their module which is in angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js

Answer (score 3):

I find in some cases, this is because no ts transpiler declared in systemjs.config.js file.
Add this in System.config function:

```
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
        tsconfig: true
    },
    meta: {
        'typescript': {
            "exports": "ts"
        }
    },
```

and in map value, add ts map like this:

```
    map: {
        'ts': 'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js'
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies within system.js

Import-Statemtents are detetced by a regex which will yield results even in case the import-statement is within a multiline-comment-block

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1408

Comment: I am getting this error in the browser : 
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:8080/LKMonitoring/node_modules/@angular/http/index.js

But I don't see any block comments or import statements in this file!
Above all this is not even my code but core angular 2 library code.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was related to `system.config.js` importing new libraries from `src` or other sub-folders instead of importing the `umd`'s from `bundles` and this way `tracer` was triggered automatically hoping to transpile some `es2015` code.

See the full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39945348/3480671), hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason behind this error,

1)Sometimes comments mentioned on top of app.component.ts file
2)pointing to incorrect umd file
3)If you are using ts(Transcript) version, please mention the transpiler options in config.js file as below or compile your all .ts file to .js file using transpiler and then reference .js file in code:

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        'angular2' : ''
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main',
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
})(this);
```