# angular2 rc4 "XHR error (404 Not Found) loading /traceur

Tags: angular

I migrate angular2 from RC2 to RC4 and now I recive the following error:

```
localhost/:36 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.ts
```

This is my systemsjs.config:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {

    //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',    
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

    //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];


    // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "emersy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.4",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Emersy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="feuerwehr, firefighter, südtirol, vigil del fuoco, alto adige, intervento, emergenza, emergency, notfall, feuer, hydrant, volonteer, freiwillig, volontario, einsatzinformationsmanagement, informationsmanagement">
    <meta name="description" content="Emersy. Das neue Informationsmanagement für Einsatzkräfte. Einfach, immer mit dabei, effizient">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <meta name="copyright" content="© 2015 Emersy">
    <meta name="geo.region" content="IT-BZ">
    <meta name="geo.position" content="46.6097665;11.192359699999997">
    <meta name="ICBM" content="46, 11">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets\img\favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\emersy.css">


    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.cookieconsent_options = { "message": "Wir verwenden Cookies für eine bestmögliche Nutzererfahrung. Durch die Nutzung unserer Internetseite erklären Sie sich damit einverstanden, dass wir Cookies auf Ihrem Gerät speichern.", "dismiss": "OK!", "theme": "dark-bottom", "learnMore": "Cookie-Richtlinien", "link": "#!cookie", };
    </script>

</head>
<base href="/">
<body>
    <noscript>
        <div class="msg error siterequirements">
            <h2>Voraussetzungen</h2>
            <p>Achtung, es scheint als ob die Ausführung von JavaScript deaktiviert ist. Dies ist für ein einwandfreies funktionieren dieser Anwendung notwendig. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Browsereinstellungen.</p>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <emersy-app>Loading....</emersy-app>
</body>
</html>
```

And my main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

My app.component.ts:

```
//Multiple lines of comments here    
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'emersy-app',
        template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR3r4.png)

Has anyone a idea. I tried the quickstarts and they works#
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the problem. One problem was the issue mention by akshay below. And the second thing was that I have used this in the system.config.js

```
'app': { main: 'main.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' }
```

instead of

```
'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

changed to js and now it works. strange in rc2 it works...

Comment: i thought my answer solved ur issue ... but still its ur question and ur wish dude which ever answer u want to mark as relevant :)

Comment: Same here, it fixed my issue. One question though @akshay Rao : is that the actual solution of a work around?

Answer (score 3):

in your app.component.ts remove the comments from the top ....

this will solve ur issue ... don't know the exact reason behind this as angular 2 is still not released so i hope the angular2 team will correct this...

you can check this out over here : -[Angular2: error at startup of the app "http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179236/angular2-error-at-startup-of-the-app-http-localhost3000-traceur-404-not-fo)

Comment: i just tried this but it doens't change my behavior