# Angular2 Heroes app throwing random error - traceur 404

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm running into the 404 traceur error when starting up my Angular2 app.

[image]

It seems a lot of people [solved it by removing multiline comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179236/angular2-error-at-startup-of-the-app-http-localhost3000-traceur-404-not-fo).

Others [updated their systemjs.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586182/angular2-rc4-xhr-error-404-not-found-loading-traceur).

I've tried both of these and neither work.

I made a [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MHqXNEd0c67JalpCoyBC?p=preview) with all my typescript and config files.

My systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: where is your traceur library located? if it isn't at the root of your site, you'll have to map the location.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'use strict';` to the top of your systemjs config file.  This happened to me a while back and if I recall, that solved it.