# angular, traceur not found

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs

my error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404   (Not Found) (traceur, line 0)


Error: invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:34
runGuarded@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:230:54
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:206:40
Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
Error loading http://localhost:3000/ts/app.js
```

my folder structure is like this:

```
index.htmn
package.json
systemjs.config.js
typings.json
->ts/app.js
->node_modules/*
->typings/*
```

I tried changing destination path of my source app file but did not have any luck.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>First App - Hello world</title>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

```
<body>
<gs-test></gs-test>
</body>
</html>
```

in systemjs.config file i tried changing map part for my app but still the same.
I also tried with changing different version of libraries but did not help.

systemjs.config.js

```
// See also: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'ts',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': {  main: 'app.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' } 
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

could be something with typings but i guess then td file would be missing. I did "typing install" before starting first time app.

typings.json

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

Please let me know what could be wrong with my setup.

tnx!
miha

Comment: You might check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022526/angular-2-404-traceur-not-found