# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TypeDecorator: Angular 2 RC-6

Tags: angular

I have had this error for over a day and I am not sure why.

app.module

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {LoginComponent} from "./Login/login";
import {LoginService} from "./Login/login.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],

    declarations: [AppComponent,
        LoginComponent],

    providers:[LoginService],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<login></login>'
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

login.model.ts

```
export class LoginModel{

    private userName: string;
    private password: string;

    constructor(userName: string='', password: string=''){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

login.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginModel} from "./login.model";
import {LoginService} from "./login.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl:'./login.html',
    styleUrls:['../css/styles.css'],

})

export class LoginComponent{

    login:LoginModel = new LoginModel();

    constructor(public loginService:LoginService){

    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.loginService.output();
    }
```

login.service

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable
export class LoginService {

    output(){
        console.log("You are in the service output class...");
    }
}
```

Currently I am just trying to get the application to compile so I can creating the routes and services. That was the whole point of the project but I keep hitting walls. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

GitHub Link

[LINK](https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue)

Comment: have you tried removing `login:LoginModel = new LoginModel();` for now?

Comment: It may be because you forgot `()` at the end of `@Injectable`, I saw somewhere on angular.io that this may cause a strange bug and they don't know why.

Comment: OMG.......... A wasted over that!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case login.service.ts was missing the `()` in `Injectable()`